# nodejs - how to fetch email from gmail

Tags: node.js, email, imap, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I have developed web application in node.js, and now I want to fetch email(s) from gmail and store in my application database. I have read/checked [mail-listener2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener2), but it give me some error about authentication. I have raised issue for that, but I am still looking for a trusted library like this. Does anybody worked with this library, or any other solution for the same? In short I am looking for a code/sample/library which is fetch email(s) (including attachment and header detail (I need uniqueid/threadid of email, so I can make a ticketing solution) from G Mail account.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try this link https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/399. What error are you getting with authentication?